# Script the windows azure command line utilities

Tags: command-line, azure

There is java based server component responsible for remote management of amazon virtual machines. I need to write an azure adapter for this component. 
I thought I would be better off using node.js based command line utils for azure management.

I wanted to know the way to invoke scripts either from c#/java and then process the output so that I could pass the output to the calling server component.

for e.g. An instruction to create a new vm will return the instance id back to the calling method.
Basically I would need to script the logic in to the adapter methods.

Any directions will be of great help.

-Sharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the technology you're choosing you have a few options:

- Using the System.Management.Automation assembly you can call any PowerShell script in a C#/.NET application
- In Java you can call a batch file that runs a PowerShell script (where you would invoke the Azure cmdlets). There's [an interesting discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/d32537bd-0aef-440e-8760-6b3085390c37/) on the MSDN forum.
- And why not use the Service Management API? This is a [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194) that makes it possible to call it from .NET, Java, Node, ...

Comment: Thanks Sandrino, Looks like REST API is the way to go. Hopefully all the operations are covered under by them.

Comment: My mistake :), Didnt know all the other libraries are just wrappers around the REST API, so should be good using the REST API's directly.